# How to change UIView's position in code?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin

I created a custom ViewCell class attached with a xib layout file, and I added some labels in xib. But when I want to change the labels' position in code, it doesn't work, can you tell me why? 
Here are the the relative codes:

```
public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();

        var bounds = ContentView.Bounds;
        UILabel label_period = RetriveViewByID ("label_period") as UILabel;
        label_period.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw;
        label_period.Text = string.Format ("{0}天之旅", m_travel_data.period); \\Works
        label_period.Frame = new RectangleF (20, label_period.Frame.Y, label_period.Frame.Width, label_period.Frame.Height);
    }
```

It is weird, because the Text is actually changed, but Frame not.

Comment: you just positioning x position to 20 in your code. What frame you need to change? x,y,width,hight?

Comment: I want to change x, but it doesn't work, nothing happened to the label.

Comment: use label_period.Frame = CGRectMake (20, label_period.Frame.origin.Y, label_period.Frame.size.Width, label_period.Frame.size.Height);

Comment: For starters, you probably meant to name the method `layoutSubviews()` rather than `LayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If so that will stop you from changing the frame of the view directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you could try here.

First of all try calling

```
label_period.SetNeedsLayout();
```

or possibly (but rather unlikely)

```
label_period.SetNeedsDisplay();
```

If neither of those work I would check to see that you do not have any unnecessary Layout Constraints declared in your .xib.

Although this was directly part of your question, I recommend instead of using `RetrieveViewByID(...)` just reference the view by its name.
(If you declared the UIViewController in the .xib you should be able to access the view inside the UIViewController with `this.label_period` )

Finally, although I do not know the specifics of your situation, I recommend switching over to Storyboards, you will run into issues like these less.

Comment: If he has **ANY** layout constraints in the xib then he is using AutoLayout. If he is using AutoLayout he **must not** change the frame of the view directly. He must update the constraints so that the view's frame gets changed to what he wants.

Comment: That is true. But it is relatively simple to get around that. `label_period.RemoveFromSuperView();
label_period.Frame = ...;
this.View.AddSubView(label_period);`

Comment: Not that i recommend doing it this way. I am just saying that it is possible.